# find and replace text with sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, text, replace

I need to replace a word in a file like this

```
text text pc text text
text text pc text text
text text pc text text
```

i need to replace pc with pc1, pc2 .... etc

```
text text pc1 text text
text text pc2 text text
text text pc3 text text
```

How can i do this in one line?

Comment: The word isn't allways on 3rd column. Actually i want this for different administration jobs that i perfom daily.Modify conf files etc... And i need to do this quickly.I cand do'it in python or c but ... there isn't allways the time... Tx for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\bpc\b/$& . ++$count/ge'
```

With awk:

```
awk -v word=pc '{gsub("\<" word "\>", word (++count)); print}'
```

If you know the word is on every line and is always in the 3rd column:

```
awk '{ $3 = $3 NR; print }'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my version in awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {count=1}; {if ($3 ~ /pc/) {sub(/pc/,"pc"(count++));print} else {print} }' inputfile
```

it only increments the counter if the $3 is pc.